# Too many requests error while creating scheduled jobs in IOT central create job API

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

We are using below IOT central api to create scheduled jobs:

API:

https://{{yourAppSubdomain}}.azureiotcentral.com/api/jobs/{{jobId}}?api-version={{dataPlaneGA}}

Issue Description:

Currently, we are getting `Too many requests` HTTP 429, error even when we are not reaching the threshold limit of 20 requests per second as per the below microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/throttling

Error:

code: 'throttled'

message: 'Too many jobs running.'

We want to know the following things:

1. Scenarios when we can get this “Too many jobs running error”.
2. Cooling time period when we can again scheduled jobs after the error.
3. Any workaround to solve/avoid this error.

Expectation is that Too many requests error should not come below thershold limit.